# Delay led in Johnny-five

Tags: javascript, arduino, johnny-five

How do I a loop in javascript with API `johnny-five/arduino`. This looping is to delay `on/off` to my led. Example:

```
while(true){
    while(time<1500){
        'led off'
    }
    while(time<1500){
        'led on'
   }

}
```

My actual code is bellow. I remove the header `http and others` and the `listen` in the end.

arduino or board on:

```
arduino.on('ready', function(){
  console.log("Arduino Pronto");

  led0 = new five.Led(13);
  led1 = new five.Led(12);
  led2 = new five.Led(11);

  this.digitalRead(10, function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
});
```

Server function:

```
  function servidor(req, res){
  var url = req.url;
  if(url == '/'){
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(fs.readFileSync('view/index.html'));
  }else if(url == '/led0'){
    res.writeHead(302, {'Location': '/'});
    res.end();
    led0.toggle();
  }else if(url == '/led1'){
    res.writeHead(302, {'Location': '/'});
    res.end();
    led1.toggle();
  }else if(url == '/led2'){
    res.writeHead(302, {'Location': '/'});
    res.end();
    led2.toggle();
  }else{
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("<h1>Erro 404</h1>");
  }

};
```

Its possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delay your LEDs using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) for a single delay or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) for a repeated delay:

```
setInterval(() => {
  led.toggle();
}, 1500);
```

This is an asynchronous delay. If you need a synchronous delay, you could use the [sleep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sleep) package or use [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) from the Node [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module: `execSync("sleep 1.5")`.